# Use swift code in objective C file in swift based project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

There are lots of question about how to use `swift code in objective c`. I had swift based project. there is Objectice C file where i need to use swift code.

Xcode did not create `ProjectName-Swift.h` automatically. So i created manually and check the following things.

1. Generated interface header name : `ProjectName-Swift.h`
2. Product Module Name : `myproject`
3. Defines Module : `YES`
4. Embedded Content Contains Swift : `YES`
5. Install Objective-C Compatibility Header : `YES`
6. Add `@objc` in swift class

import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

**@objc** class User: NSObject, NSCoding
{
}

Then `Import ProjectName-Swift.h` in objective c file. But gives error `Unknown Type name User`

I had tried with add `@class User` It gives error **forward reference using @class**

How can I fix this erros

Comment: There are two headers. You have confused them. You cannot manually create the generated interface header. It is not part of the project.

Comment: @matt can you please explain more. I am still confused

Comment: @SunnyShah , Apple already explained it very easy way , please read it carefully - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: @SunnyShah how did you manage to solve this problem? Where did you found that file to import swift class?

Comment: You could also get this error when placing 'MyProject-Swift.h' within  #ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED or #if DEBUG - then it works in simulator but not when building a release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you have already solved the problem after reading the documentation referenced by @AnupamMishra, but just in case: try removing from the project the `ProjectName-Swift.h` file that you created manually.  It hides the file of the same name auto-generated by Xcode and not listed in your project.  The file is still there, somewhere deep in the DerivedData directory.

Another observation: you didn't have to set `Objective-c Generated Interface Header Name` in `Build Settings`.  Xcode would generate one and name it `myproject-Swift.h` by default, since `myproject` is your `Product Module Name`.